# Adding settings class to a UWP app

Tags: c#, settings, win-universal-app, appsettings, windows-10-universal

I'm developing a Universal Windows Platform app but there is no Settings template in Visual Studio.

How can I implement an easy, strongly typed and observable class that stores my settings in LocalSettings or RoamingSettings?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317127/hidden-advertisement-as-spam

Answer (score 57):

1. Create a new class inheriting from ObservableSettings.
2. Call to the base class constructor indicating if you want to store the settings in **LocalSettings** or in **RoamingSettings**.
3. Add all your properties calling the base class members 
   **Set** and **Get** in the getter and in the setter. No need to pass the name of the property or use **nameof()** operator!
4. Optionally you can set a default value decorating the property with **DefaultSettingValue** attribute.

Here an example of a settings class:

```
namespace Test
{
    public class Settings : ObservableSettings
    {
        private static Settings settings = new Settings();
        public static Settings Default
        {
            get { return settings; }
        }

        public Settings()
            : base(ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings)
        {
        }

        [DefaultSettingValue(Value = 115200)]
        public int Bauds
        {
            get { return Get<int>(); }
            set { Set(value); }
        }

        [DefaultSettingValue(Value = "Jose")]
        public string Name
        {
            get { return Get<string>(); }
            set { Set(value); }
        }

    }
}
```

and here how to add an instance in your app.xaml:

```
<Application
    x:Class="Test.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Test"
    RequestedTheme="Light">
    <Application.Resources>
        <local:Settings x:Key="settings"/>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Access and modify the values in a MVVM fashion:

```
<Page
    x:Class="Test.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Test"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    DataContext="{StaticResource settings}">

    <StackPanel Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <TextBlock Text="Bauds"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Default.Bauds, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Name"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Default.Name, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Page>
```

Everything will be stored properly in your settings repository.

Here you have the implementation of **DefaultSettingValue** and **ObservableSettings**:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Reflection;
using System.ComponentModel;
using Windows.Storage;


[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false)]
public sealed class DefaultSettingValueAttribute : Attribute
{
    public DefaultSettingValueAttribute()
    {
    }

    public DefaultSettingValueAttribute(object value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public object Value { get; set; }
}

public class ObservableSettings : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private readonly ApplicationDataContainer settings;

    public ObservableSettings(ApplicationDataContainer settings)
    {
        this.settings = settings;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected bool Set<T>(T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (settings.Values.ContainsKey(propertyName))
        {
            var currentValue = (T)settings.Values[propertyName];
            if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(currentValue, value))
                return false;
        }

        settings.Values[propertyName] = value;
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        return true;
    }

    protected T Get<T>([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (settings.Values.ContainsKey(propertyName))
            return (T)settings.Values[propertyName];

        var attributes = GetType().GetTypeInfo().GetDeclaredProperty(propertyName).CustomAttributes.Where(ca => ca.AttributeType == typeof(DefaultSettingValueAttribute)).ToList();
        if (attributes.Count == 1)
            return (T)attributes[0].NamedArguments[0].TypedValue.Value;

        return default(T);
    }
```

You can download a solution with a functional example from the repository I created in [**GitHub**](https://github.com/joseangelmt/ObservableSettings).