# How to know when an app is run for the first time

Tags: c#, uwp

How to check if the app is opened for the first time to make a welcome screen.

Comment: For UWP settings https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.localsettings.aspx, or fancy class from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35470460/adding-settings-class-to-a-uwp-app

Answer (score 1):

You could use settings to store a boolean value, or write a small piece of data to a file to know if it has been opened before. Just check the data and viola, you have a first time running check.